# File loop and logic in controller of view header?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, autoload

I have the following in the header.php file which is included in all of my views:

```
$dh = opendir(Vs.get_class($this).'/js') ;
while($script = readdir($dh)) {
    if(!is_dir($script))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/'.$script.'"></script>' ;
    }
}

$dh = opendir(Vs.get_class($this).'/css') ;
while($css = readdir($dh)) {
    if(!is_dir($css))
    {
        echo '<link type="text/css" href="css/'.$css.'" rel="stylesheet"/>' ;
    }
}
```

It's purpose is to autoload all the css and JS files for a particular view (which has the same name as the controller, hence `get_class`).

Should all this be a part of the associated controller or is how I have done it fine?

Comment: AUW this code hurts my eyes

Comment: Wow :) Some of the worst PHP code I've seen in a long time - possibly ever! As long as things exist it looks OK-ish...

Comment: To the people commenting above me .. the purpose of SO is to learn, not to mock others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude just use Glob php function . And then include those.. it will work perfectly fine. Also you will need to pass the absolute path

```
foreach (glob("*.css") as $filename) 
{ 
   echo '<link type="text/css" href="css/'.$filename.'" rel="stylesheet"/>' ; 
}
```

Comment: For a good answer, place example code including 'Glob'. It'll help answer the OP's question, help others in the future, and you'll be more likely to get up-voted.

Comment: @kuldeep Thanks, looking into it now. Can you provide an example where I'd match css and js files?

Comment: foreach (glob("*.css") as $filename) {
    echo '<link type="text/css" href="css/'.$filename.'" rel="stylesheet"/>' ;
}

Comment: @kuldeep Put this in your actual answer (edit it) and use backticks for `code` :)

Comment: @Jimbo I added it to the answer :)

Comment: @kuldeep Cool, now that'll be more likely to help people in the future that visit this post, and it's more likely that you'll get more upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Scripts and stuff which are only and exclusively used in *the View* belong in *the View*. The controller has nothing to do with it.

Views don't need to be dumb. In fact, they *shouldn't* be. They need to care about everything that has to do with preparing and returning a response. That even includes setting HTTP headers and possible caching logic. Including necessary CSS and JS scripts is also part of its job.